# Is it possible to shrinkwrap wrapped contents?

Tags: html, css

If you use a `<span>` tag for your container and set it to `display: inline-block`, then the container will *shrinkwrap* the contents, **unless the contents wraps onto multiple lines**, in which case the width of the container simply defaults to 100%. Is there any way to shrinkwrap wrapped contents? Here's my code (http://jsfiddle.net/T8uGm/):

**HTML**

```
<span class="wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="block"></a>
    <a href="#" class="block"></a>
    <a href="#" class="block"></a>
    <a href="#" class="block"></a>
    <a href="#" class="block"></a>
    <a href="#" class="block"></a>
    <a href="#" class="block"></a>
</span>​
```

**CSS**

```
.block {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this css:

```
.block {
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 100px; /* The fix minimum width of span/div */
        width: 19.5%;  /* Depending how much box in 1 row. Exm: 5 block = 20% (19.5% to give space) */
        height: 100px;
        background: blue;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Fredy. The only problem is I want my width and height to be the same. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: @danielfaraday : You must use the javascript like jquery / motools, because the css has not been able to "shrinkwrap". Are you planning to make a fluid-web?

Answer (score -1):

Use `white-space:nowrap;`

```
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px black;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/T8uGm/5/)**

Comment: Is it possible to shrinkwrap *wrapped* contents?

Comment: Both answers so far simply remove wrapping. I still want my elements to wrap, but I also want to eliminate any excess white space. Does that make sense?